# Property 'itemRows' comes from an index signature, so it must be accessed with ['itemRows']

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am getting 2 errors and can someone help me.
These are errors

Property `itemRows` comes from an index signature, so it must be accessed with `['itemRows']`.

8                 `<ng-container *ngIf="FormGroup.controls.itemRows!=null">`

`Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.`

9                     `<div *ngFor="let itemrow of FormGroup.controls.itemRows.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">`

These are my files.

**panel-list.component.html**

```
<form novalidate [formGroup]="FormGroup">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 form-group marL40">
            <div style="margin-top: 0px;" formGroupName="itemRows">
                <div class="row panel-heading text-bold" style="text-align: lesft; margin-top:0px; margin-left:10px;">
                    Form Details
                </div>
                <ng-container *ngIf="FormGroup.controls.itemRows!=null">
                    <div *ngFor="let itemrow of FormGroup.controls.itemRows.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
                                <input matInput placeholder="Name" formControlName="Name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
                                <input matInput placeholder="RollNo" formControlName="RollNo">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
                                <input matInput placeholder="Class" formControlName="Class">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
                                <input matInput placeholder="MobileNo" formControlName="MobileNo">
                            </div>
                    
                            <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
                                <button (click)="deleteRow(i)" class="btn btn-danger">
                                    X
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    
                    </div>
                    </ng-container>
                    <div class="form-group" style="text-align: right;">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addNewRow()">ADD</button>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**panel-list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-panel-list',
  templateUrl: './panel-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./panel-list.component.css']
})
export class PanelListComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'Test';
  FormGroup!: FormGroup;
  TotalRow!: number;

  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.FormGroup = this._fb.group({
      itemRows: this._fb.array([this.initItemRow()])
    });
  }

  initItemRow(){
    return this._fb.group({
      Name: [''],
      RollNo: [''],
      Class: [''],
      MobileNo: ['']
    });
  }

  addNewRow(){
    const control = <FormArray>this.FormGroup.controls['itemRows'];
    control.push(this.initItemRow());
  }

  deleteRow(index: number){
    const control = <FormArray>this.FormGroup.controls['itemRows'];
    if(control != null){
      this.TotalRow = control.value.length;
    }
    if(this.TotalRow>1){
      control.removeAt(index);
    }else{
      alert('one record is mandotary');
    }
  }


}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/layout/header/header.component';
import { OrganizationsListComponent } from './components/organization/organizations-list/organizations-list.component';
import { CreateOrganizationComponent } from './components/organization/create-organization/create-organization.component';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AdminLayoutComponent } from './components/layout/admin-layout/admin-layout.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './components/layout/footer/footer.component';
import { SidebarComponent } from './components/layout/sidebar/sidebar.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/layout/navbar/navbar.component';
import { CreateDepartmentComponent } from './components/departments/create-department/create-department.component';
import { DepartmentsListComponent } from './components/departments/departments-list/departments-list.component';
import { ViewDepartmentComponent } from './components/departments/view-department/view-department.component';
import { ViewTeamComponent } from './components/teams/view-team/view-team.component';
import { CreateTeamComponent } from './components/teams/create-team/create-team.component';
import { TeamListComponent } from './components/teams/team-list/team-list.component';
import { EditOrganizationComponent } from './components/organization/edit-organization/edit-organization.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/auth/login/login.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './components/auth/signup/signup.component';
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';
import { DepartmentHeadLayoutComponent } from './components/layout/department-head-layout/department-head-layout.component';
import { TeamMemberLayoutComponent } from './components/layout/team-member-layout/team-member-layout.component';
import { AdminDashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/admin-dashboard/admin-dashboard.component';
import { EditTeamComponent } from './components/teams/edit-team/edit-team.component';
import { EditDepartmentComponent } from './components/departments/edit-department/edit-department.component';
import { AuthInterceptor } from './interceptors/auth.interceptor';
import { CreatePAComponent } from './components/pa-sheet/create-pa/create-pa.component';
import { ViewPAComponent } from './components/pa-sheet/view-pa/view-pa.component';
import { PaListComponent } from './components/pa-sheet/pa-list/pa-list.component';
import { EditPaComponent } from './components/pa-sheet/edit-pa/edit-pa.component';
import { LandingPageComponent } from './components/landing-page/landing-page.component';

import { PanelListComponent } from './components/layout/panel-list/panel-list.component';
import { ReviweeListComponent } from './components/layout/reviwee-list/reviwee-list.component';
import { ReviwerListComponent } from './components/layout/reviwer-list/reviwer-list.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    OrganizationsListComponent,
    CreateOrganizationComponent,
    AdminLayoutComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    SidebarComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    CreateDepartmentComponent,
    DepartmentsListComponent,
    ViewDepartmentComponent,
    EditDepartmentComponent,
    ViewTeamComponent,
    TeamListComponent,
    CreateTeamComponent,
    EditTeamComponent,
    EditOrganizationComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    SignupComponent,
    DepartmentHeadLayoutComponent,
    TeamMemberLayoutComponent,
    CreatePAComponent,
    ViewPAComponent,
    PaListComponent,
    EditPaComponent,
    AdminDashboardComponent,
    AdminDashboardComponent,
    LandingPageComponent,
    PanelListComponent,
    ReviweeListComponent,
    ReviwerListComponent 
    
  ],
  imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, HttpClientModule, FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule],
  providers: [AuthService,{
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: AuthInterceptor,
    multi: true
  }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular doesn't understand what type of data in component page.You must copy the data and move in to typescript file.This error is caused due to Ahead of Time Compilation.

```
<div *ngFor="let itemrow of FormGroup.controls.itemRows.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
```

**change to**

```
<div *ngFor="let itemrow of getItemRow; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
```

**In typescript file**

```
get getItemRow {
    return (this.FormGroup.controls.itemRows as FormArray).controls;
}
```